# <Google> Must specify extras for registerAdNetworkExtras:?

Tags: ios, admob

I'm receiving a message in Xcode's debug area stating :

Must specify extras for registerAdNetworkExtras:

I didn't get this error yesterday but today I'm getting it on debug area out of nowhere. I didn't change my code in any way. Is this an error on google's end? Why am I receiving this message?

My code to get AdMob banner:

```
   adMobView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];

  adMobView.adUnitID =  @"unit-id";
  adMobView.rootViewController = self;
  GADRequest *request =[GADRequest request];
  request.testDevices = @[ @"testdeviceID" ];
  [adMobView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: I Have the same problem here, i think that is not an error, but just a message...do you use admob mediation?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/extras$20for$20registerAdNetworkExtras/google-admob-ads-sdk/UQfS_htdQ4c/FfxFMOHDBGQJ) i found the right answer, is a last version SDK issue, that don't have effect on the mediation/ad serving functionality. Hope this help.

More info: Ram Parameswaran (Mobile SDK Team) say: "This issue does not affect functionality and can be ignored for the time being. Changes will be made to address the issue and pushed out in a future release."

Comment: Please post some content from the link.